# Execution flow of times iterator and for loop in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby we have a times iterator and I have read in [some blog](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1cqdp89_kolr4q1YAQaB-6i5GXip8MHyve8MvQ_1r6_s) that

> Variables declared in *blocks passed to iterators* (e.g., `times` or `each`) are undefined at the top of *each* iteration!

so when I try to execute

```
3.times do |loop_num|
   sum ||= 0
   sum += 1
   puts sum
end
```

it gives me output

```
1
1
1
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

and if I do same with for loop

```
for loop_num in 1..3
  sum ||= 0
  sum += 1
  puts sum
end
```

Output is

```
1
2
3
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

but now when I again execute the times iterator it is giving me output as

```
4
5
6
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

So can any one explain this behavior, why it is not assigning the sum with 0 instead taking its value as 3(which is last value assigned to sum in for loop) and giving results as 4 5 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because `3.times` is executing a block while the `for .. in` loop is executing in the same context it is called. This is where closures come into play.

In your first example, `sum` hasn't been defined anywhere that the block can access it. Therefore, `sum` is re-defined each time the block is executed. If you add a `puts sum` statement after the block, you will see that `sum` is undefined.

For the for loop example, you stay in the same context so the second time through the loop `sum` has already been defined in the context so it uses the existing value. You can verify this by adding a `puts sum` statement after the loop and you will see that it has the last value that it was set to in the loop.

When you execute your `3.times` block after you have executed your loop, `sum` exists in the closure so the block uses the already defined variable instead of re-defining it each time through the loop.

Comment: In case of for loop we have sum variable don't you think the scope of this variable is inside the for loop so how it is accessible outside the loop.

Comment: @Sabahat `for` loops don't have an own scope. There's no difference between "outside the loop" and "inside the loop".

Comment: @Stefan: The ISO Ruby Language Specification makes this really clear. It specifies that `for`/`in` desugars to `each`, and then makes a reference to the paragraph which specifies how blocks are evaluated but says that `for`/`in` skips one sentence … and that sentence is exactly the one which sets up a new execution context. So, the ISO spec quite literally explicitly says: `for` *is* `each` **except for scope**.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think you are right, but to be honest, I don't really understand the spec. It does say that `for` skips 11.3.3 Step c) which pushes an empty set of local variable bindings onto the current stack. The new context (Eb) however is already created in Step b) which is not skipped (according to the spec). From my understanding, new variables would end up in the new context (Eb) and could not propagate to the outer context (Eo).

Answer (score 3):

This is somehow expected. According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop): (emphasis added)

> The `for` loop is similar to using `each`, but **does not create a new variable scope**.

In Ruby, regular methods like [`times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), [`loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) or `each` do create a new variable scope, whereas [control expressions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html) like `for`, `while` or `until` do not.

Therefore, this code:

```
for loop_num in 1..3
  sum ||= 0
  sum += 1
  puts sum
end

3.times do
  sum ||= 0
  sum += 1
  puts sum
end
```

Is equivalent to:

```
sum ||= 0
sum += 1
puts sum

sum ||= 0
sum += 1
puts sum

sum ||= 0
sum += 1
puts sum

3.times do
  sum ||= 0
  sum += 1
  puts sum
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @rdubya's answer, you're misinterpreting the blog post quote.

What the post means is that in this code block:

```
3.times do |t|
  puts defined?(var_only_in_block) ? true : false
  var_only_in_block = 1
end
# false
# false
# false
```

each iteration destroys the variable `var_only_in_block` after running, which makes it undefined at the start of the next iteration.

However, blocks have access to variables in the scope they were defined in. Take this example:

```
var_outside_block = 1
3.times do |t|
  var_outside_block += 1
  puts var_outside_block
end
# => 2
# => 3
# => 4
```

Because the variable was defined outside of the block, changes made during each iteration are preserved.

Comment: The quote says "undefined", it's not about (re)assigning a default value.

Comment: Was just in the middle of editing my answer when you made that comment.